# How to safely delete a row shown to the user using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page where I display contents from a MySQL table. I want to add a "delete button" on each row so the user can delete the displayed contents.

The fact is, I though about adding a "value=id" attribute but would that be safe? For example, wouldn't the user be able to inspect element, edit the source and change the value to be deleted?

Thank you.

> NOTE: I'm not really using buttons, but instead "a" tags. I'm not sure this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a tag, pass a hash value of id along id, there are many php hash functions to achive this, add your custom salt to it, on the other side you take id and hash it again using the same method, and you compare it to incoming hash.

But if its an end user, it means you already have authentication, which will provide further security againsts automatic deletes, just make sure id that user deletes is his content, so that users dont delete each others content.

Using button or a tag isnt relevant, as ultimately you are sending parameters to a url.

Comment: That's probably my best solution. But it still creeps me the fact that I can't be safe about what I want to delete.

Comment: this is the only way, and its safe - 2 ways of securing: 1) user authorization 2) parameter hashing.  No need to worry.

Comment: You could always save abackup of that row that is being deleted, have another table and copy that content there along with id of who deleted it and when. Dont forget to accept my answer))

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have a session for logged in user and each user has own contents created by him. So you have to:

- Make route for deleting content by content ID.
- When the route executed you have to check if user has session or
  not.

**if not** -> redirect him to the content page.
**if he has session**-> you need to check if this user created this post or not.

**if not** -> redirect him to content page.
**if yes**-> fire the delete function and delete the content.